# Photoshop CS6 - How to stop Round Shape merging colors with background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shapes, anti-aliasing

This seems like a simple issue and I found dozens of answers around this site and the web, but none of those has fixed my issue.

I'm trying to add a shape with rounded corners. I want the colors to be solid but they are blending with the background. I'm going to be making 100s of images, so I didn't want to have to copy & paste to a new layer and try and crop the off-color parts (like some of the solutions call for).

Any simple solution will be very much appreciated. If I have to use Illustrator I could, but I would prefer not to.

[image: Image#1]
[image: Image#2]

Comment: It's called anti-aliasing and you can't turn it off for live shape layers, you can turn it off in *fill pixels* mode though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to disable anti-aliasing, as it will degrade the quality of the rounded corner. Unless you are making pixel art or something. It's a bit unclear how or where you'd be using this image, but if I were to use this red rectangle as its own image, I'd perhaps save it by itself with a transparent background and in .png or .svg format... Or in some other cases: .tiff, .pdf or .psd. [Wikipedia example of aliasing and anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#/media/File:Aliasing_a.png)

Comment: I'm making nicer looking buttons for a simple application that only can use.bmp files. Images I am making are from 100x100 to 500x200. The program uses pink (ff00ff) as the transparent color, so I wanted to use round buttons but the anti-aliasing is causing me to have red (or green,blue etc)  button with a slight bit of pink around it.  I was trying to save time by using shapes to make re-sizing faster... But I think using pixels and making the 5 buttons sizes I need, then filling it with the color I want will be the best way. I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you have to export the image as .BMP, which doesn't accept transparency. As such, anything you export that has a transparency will have a color background added. Therefore, your best alternatives would be to either:

1. Deactivate anti-alias for the shapes (but in this case the rounded corner will not look so smooth)
2. add a background that matches the color of the area where the button will be placed (if the button will be over a solid color, might be your best choice)

Comment: Since  bmp doesn't support transparency, what good does disabling anti-aliasing do? Even if you disable anti-aliasing, with rounded corners you'd still need transparency. Your second option is on point though.

Comment: @Joonas that would prevent colors from blending with the background, which OP also states in the question.

Comment: I don't think he realizes what that would mean in terms of quality.

Comment: OP states specifically "I want the colors to be solid". How do you know it's not what he/she wants?

Comment: I'm not saying I know what he wants, but there's the solution that offers good rounded corner quality and then there's the solution for what op wants, that offers bad rounded corner quality. I'm not here to force his hand or yours for that matter, but unless he is making some sort of pixel art stuff, disabling anti-aliasing sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with you, but since I have no idea what end result OP wanted, I just tried to give the best answer based solely on what's being asked